# Convert long to time

Tags: sql, postgresql

In java I have a field type: *java.sql.Time*

I want to store it to postgresql in type long. I created a view in Postgresql and I want to display it to time format (HH:mm). Can I do that?

Please help

Comment: You could convert the time to an integer (seconds) and store it in the long field. During reading just extract the hours and minutes from it. Why do you want to store a time in bigint (I assume you mean bigint by PostgreSQL long)?

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in Postgres (that's Oracle). The equivalent is PL/pgSQL, but that can only be used in stored functions, not views. I removed the plsql reference

Comment: Also: it would be much easier if you just stored the time in a `time` column. Why do you want to store it as a long value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is not the stupidest way you could store time. I've seen a Postgres table that stored time as _radians_! I have no idea why.

Comment: @Shired_Resident I stored it in long because Java Time easy to convert to long and long to Time, anyway I don't know if there are any better way to store it.

Comment: @SeSong if you store it as time (which is a type in Postgres) then no conversions are necessary. It is a better way to store it.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do this. We have a time type!

```
select to_char((46400 / 86400.0) * interval '24 hours', 'HH:MI');
 to_char
---------
 12:53
(1 row)
```

Comment: I don't want to convert my Time to second, I store getTime() as long, when I get it back I use setTime(long) so I don't need to convert. I use Time datatype because my application use ZK timebox on my view for user input data

Comment: @SeSong So in the question you said "I want to store it to postgresql in type long. I created a view in Postgresql and I want to display it to time format (HH:mm). Can I do that?" And this is the answer to that question. Now you're saying you don't want to store it as a long and display it as time? I'm not clear on what else you could have meant.

Comment: your ways is convert time to second, but Java Time.getTime() at 12:00 PM today equal to 1,455,170,400,000 as millisecond. But one day has only 86,400,000 millisecond. java time maybe include date.